# neo4j browser credential timeout not working

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to make the neo4j browser more secure by trying to get it to forget user credentials. I've tried adding both these lines to me neo4j.conf but they don't seem to have any effect.

```
browser.credential_timeout=7200s
browser.retain_connection_credentials=false
```

I can still come back a day later and have full access through the neo4j browser without entering my credentials again. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you restart Neo4j after making those changes? And refresh Neo4j Browser?

Comment: Yes, I did both of those things...